# Dependent Forms in Symfony 2.7 Error: getId() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create Dependent Forms using Symfony 2.7 with custom query builder but the PRE_SUBMIT keeps instantiating wrong object.

I have uploaded the entire code in [github](https://github.com/gghhh456/DependentForms) with some data `sampleData.sql`.

CityType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder,array$options){

    $builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'TestMyBundle:Country',
        'choice_label' => 'country'
    ));
    $builder->add('Search','submit');

    $stateFormbuilder = function(FormInterface $form,$country_Id){
        $search = $form->get('Search');
        $form->remove('Search');
        $form->add('state','entity',array(
            'class'=>'TestMyBundle:State',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $repository) use ($country_Id){
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('State')
                                    ->where('State.countryId= :countryId')
                                    ->setParameter('countryId',$country_Id)
                                    ->orderBy('State.state','ASC')
                                    ;
            }
        ));
    };
    $CityFormbuilder = function(FormInterface $form, $state_Id){
        $form->add('city','entity',array(
            'class'=>'TestMyBundle:City',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $repository) use ($state_Id){
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('City')
                                  ->where('City.countryId= :countryId')
                                    ->setParameter('City.stateId',$state_Id)
                                    ->orderBy('City.city','ASC')
                                    ;
            }
        ));
    };
    $CityAreaFormBuilder = function(FormInterface $form, $city_Id){
        $form->add('cityArea','entity',array(
            'class'=>'TestMyBundle:CityArea',
            'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $repository) use ($city_Id){
                return $repository->createQueryBuilder('CityArea')
                    ->where('CityArea.city= :cityId')
                    ->setParameter('CityArea.cityId',$city_Id)
                    ->orderBy('CityArea.cityArea','ASC')
                    ;
            }
        ));
        $form->add('Search','submit');
    };
    //$CityFormbuilder, $CityAreaFormBuilder
    //$builder->add('Search', 'submit');
    // State
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use($stateFormbuilder) {
        $country = $event->getData();
        $country_id = null;
        if(null!== $country){
            $country_id = $country->getId();
        }
        $stateFormbuilder($event->getForm(),$country_id);
    });
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,function(FormEvent $event) use($stateFormbuilder){
        $data = $event->getData();
        $country_id = array_key_exists('id',$data) ? $data['id']:null;
        $stateFormbuilder($event->getForm(),$country_id);
    });
    // City
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use($CityFormbuilder) {
        $state = $event->getData();
        $stateId = null;
        if(null!==$state){
            $stateId = $state->getId();
        }
        $CityFormbuilder($event->getForm(),$stateId);
    });
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,function(FormEvent $event) use($CityFormbuilder){
        $data = $event->getData();
        $city_id = array_key_exists('id',$data) ? $data['id']:null;
        $CityFormbuilder($event->getForm(),$city_id);
    });
    // City Area
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use($CityAreaFormBuilder) {
        $cityArea = $event->getData();
        $cityAreaId = null;
        if(null!==$cityArea){
            $cityAreaId= $cityArea->getId();
        }
        $CityAreaFormBuilder($event->getForm(),$cityAreaId);
    });
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,function(FormEvent $event) use($CityAreaFormBuilder){
        $data = $event->getData();
        $cityArea_Id = array_key_exists('id',$data) ? $data['id']:null;
        $CityAreaFormBuilder($event->getForm(),$cityArea_Id);
    });
}
```

[My Stack Trace](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/923b4bc7541e2359f13a)

> Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class), if no data is passed to the form, `$event->getData()` is null.

For each of your 3 `EventListener`s that uses the `PRE_SET_DATA` event,
Add the following check (I take the last event as example) :

```
$state = $event->getData();
$stateId = null;

if (null !== $state) {
    $stateId = $state->getId();
}
```

Then, do your logic depending on the value of `$stateId`.

Comment: Okay I changed my code and updated the same in the question but now it says  **Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given** though I am using querybuilder object

Comment: It's a totally different problem but can you please give me the line where the error occurs ? The best would be to add the full exception trace in your question.

Comment: I updated the question with the stack Trace... And it does not shows me the line where it occurs in my code it points to EntityType in Vendors folder.

Comment: In your Type, for each QueryBuilder, you have to remove `->getQuery()->getResult()`, only pass the QueryBuilder itself, not the query or its results. It's surely the origin of your main problem. See the [EntityType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder)

Comment: Ohh thanks... I am now able to get the form and as well retrieve the values for select options using ajax script. However When I submit the form it says ** This value is not valid.** But I am able to see the data that I passed with `$formData = $request->request->all(); var_dump($formData);`

Comment: The message you given is part of a validation error that corresponds to a constraint that you added on a specific field (or added because of the type of your field). Fill your fields with values that corresponds to the their Type, and that matches with constraints and you'll avoid the error. If your question is answered, you should accept the answer in order that people with the same problem can find it easily.